# Split a string into exactly N pieces

Tags: python, string, algorithm, logic

Given a number N and a string, I need to split the string into **exactly** N pieces.

For example, if N=3

- abcd -> ["ab", "c", "d"]
- abcde -> ["ab", "cd", "e"]
- abcdef -> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
- abcdefg -> ["abc", "de", "fg"]

What would be the best way to achieve this (preferably in python)?

My current (not working well enough) solution is

```
chunkSize = int(ceil(len(myString) / float(numOfChunks)))
chunks = [myString[i:i+chunkSize ] for i in range(0, len(myString), chunkSize )]
```

Comment: I don't get it. I'm counting 3 pieces.

Comment: Why the specific distribution when not exactly divisible, and why not `['a', 'b', 'cd']` and `['a', 'bc', 'de']` and `['ab', 'cd', 'efg']`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. I meant 3.
If it was 4, then for example: 
abcde -> ["ab", "c", "d", "e"]

Comment: What is the criteria to split? I mean, "abcd" could also be split into ["a", "b", "cd"] or ["a", "bc", "d"] or others ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A generator that divides an input sequence into even chunks:

```
def split_into(s, n):
    size, remainder = divmod(len(s), n)
    start = 0
    for i in range(n):
        length = size + (i < remainder)
        yield s[start:start + length]
        start += length
```

This uses the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True == 1`.

Demo:

```
>>> list(split_into('abcd', 3))
['ab', 'c', 'd']
>>> list(split_into('abcde', 3))
['ab', 'cd', 'e']
>>> list(split_into('abcdef', 3))
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
>>> list(split_into('abcdefg', 3))
['abc', 'de', 'fg']
>>> list(split_into('abcdefgh', 3))
['abc', 'def', 'gh']
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I had in mind.
I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: That's a lovely function and answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudocode. I don't know Python, but probably useful as a general purpose algorithm.

```
RegLen <- Int(Len(Str)/N)   # The integer portion only
FirstLen = Len(Str) - N * RegLen
# Output goes into Output[] array of length N elements, each a substring

Output[1] = Left(Str, FirstLen)

For i <- 2 to N
   StartPosition <- FirstLen + (i-2) * RegLen + 1
   Output[i] <- Mid(Str, StartPosition, RegLen)
Loop
```